# How can I use enhanced for loop for two separate List arrays?

Tags: list, for-loop, arraylist, selenium-webdriver, foreach

```
    List <WebElement> statusArr = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector(".icono-exclamationCircle.ng-scope"));
    List <WebElement> flagArr = new ArrayList<WebElement>();
```

This are my two separate list arrays. I want to iterate them both in parallel manner. How can I do that?
They both have same number of elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give this a try

```
for(int i = 0; i < statusArr.size(); i++){
    statusArr.get(i);
    flagArr.get(i);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript you can't iterate two lists in parallel in the same execution. They can only be iterated sequentially.